# NodeJS can't connect to XERO

Tags: node.js, xero-api

I am using xero as my accounting software. I have one requirement that part of my application need to be integrated with xero to perform automation. Using the nodejs sdk seems so easy, but the fact is i cannot connect to xero even using the simplest example. Here is the code:

```
const xero = require('xero-node');

const config = {
  "userAgent": "Firefox",
  "consumerKey": "<MY_CONSUMER_KEY>",
  "consumerSecret": "<MY_CONSUMER_SECRET>",
  "privateKeyPath": "./privatekey.pem"
};

const xeroClient = new xero.PrivateApplication(config);

xeroClient.core.contacts.getContacts()
  .then(contacts => {
    console.log(contacts);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The code does nothing and prints no error. Anyone ever deal with this problem?

Comment: You probably already did this but make sure you are triggering the code to run. Like a put `console.log` to confirm that that page is actually being executed. It is kind of hard to debug when there is no feedback whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that your privatekey is invalid. If you put these lines(https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/pull/169/files) into your module then it will check it first.

You could also copy a few of those lines and validate your privateKey.

At the moment the SDK swallows the exception when the key is invalid.

Also, please make sure you are running server side - not browser side.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I need to add following code:

```
if (config.privateKeyPath && !config.privateKey) 
      config.privateKey = fs.readFileSync(config.privateKeyPath);
```